# What do we call a doctor's prediction

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, terminology

Say my doctor tells me that my grandfather has only a few months to live.

What do we call such a prediction based on a medical condition?

Comment: @HotLicks I heard of someone who went to the funeral of a doctor who had earlier told him he only had months to live.

Comment: @WS2 What is the word for that?  Irony?

Comment: @Centaurus I did also hear of a chap who got committed to a psychiatric hospital, but shortly thereafter discharged himself saying the doctors were more stupid than he was.

Comment: @WS2 and friends: The etymology of *prognosis* notwithstanding, doctors are not fortune tellers. They work with data which yield median survival statistics. He may have heard, "you will die in 2 months" but it's likely that what was said was closer to, "based on your diagnosis of X disease at Y stage, the median survival is 2 months."(Standard deviation available upon request.) If he goes on and lives a year, the issue is not that the doctor was *wrong* but that the patient didn't understand *probability*. (Understandably so, for the dying patient - not so much for the commentators on SE :-))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The word is **"[prognosis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prognosis)"**. (Merriam-Webster dictionary)

> 1: a doctor's opinion about how someone will recover from an illness or injury
>
> 2: a judgment about what is going to happen in the future

- "It's a very good prognosis. She will recover completely"
- "He's undergone surgery plus chemotherapy. Still it's a somber prognosis."
- "What is my prognosis, doctor?   Very good, Mrs Barnard. The tumor has been removed and you are cured."

Comment: Not too sure about the "somber prognosis" or the "prognosis is somber". Perhaps "cautious" or "reserved" is better suited. Your 3rd example reads like an outdated line from the series Dr. Kildare 

Comment: And I am delighted to have it confirmed to me by my dictionary that the wonderful word *prognostication* does exist - meaning 'a prophecy'.

Comment: Diagnosis is knowledge of what's wrong with you, and prognosis is knowledge of what's expected to happen next... are there any more "...gnos" words? I see a few like "cognos..." and of course "agnos..." but that's about it...

Comment: @Mari-LouA In medicine we use the word "somber" in this context.

Comment: @Joffan there's "gnosis" and "gnostic"; and wonderfully there is [prosopagnosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopagnosia).

Comment: @MattGutting -- Really?  I can't see it.

Comment: @WS2 I think you misunderstood me. "Giving herself away" referred to your mention of "the 1960's" and, consequently, somebody's age.

Comment: You mean I've been using "proboscis" wrong all these years!?

Answer (score 3):

**Medicine**: *prognosis* (a prediction of) the likely outcome of a disease in a general or particular case... the alternative word is "*prognostication*"

Comment: *Prognostication* is the act of making a prognosis.  It is not a substitute for *prognosis*.

Comment: Exactly...thought I might contribute to some rewriting.

Comment: @Jim The OED does recognise *prognostication* as an exact synonym of *prognosis*, as well as the act of making such. It is however stated nowadays to be 'rare'.